# Differentiability of stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $Z_t = 1\{X\geq t\}$, where $X$ is continuously distributed.

The trajectories of  $Z$, i.e. $t\mapsto Z_t(\omega)$ have derivative zero everywhere, except for a single point $t_\omega$. Can I conclude that since $X$ is continuously distributed, the derivative of $Z_t$ is zero a.s (or in $L_p$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trajectories are a.e. constant: 
$$
Z_t(\omega) = \begin{cases} 1\quad t \leq X(\omega),  \\
0 \quad t > X(\omega) \end{cases}.
$$
So we have that
$$
\Bbb P\Bigl( \omega \in \Omega : Z_t'(\omega) = 0 \Bigr) = \Bbb P\Bigl( \omega \in \Omega :X(\omega) \neq t \Bigr) , \quad \text{for all} \ t \geq 0.
$$
which is equal to $1$ if $X$ has a continuous distribution. So for fixed $t \geq 0$ the paths of $Z$ are a.s. differentiable at $t$.
But 
$$
\Bbb P\Bigl( \omega \in \Omega : t \mapsto Z_t(\omega)  \  \text{is differentiable for all} \ t \geq 0 \Bigr) = 0 
$$
So no path is differentiable as a whole.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Do you think there is a way to define derivative in some sense here? My original motivation was to see whether the following object has any meaning: $\mathbb{E}[\sup_t|Z'_t|]$. For which I thought that we would need a.s. differentiability, right?

Comment: Well, you can define the first derivative of $t \mapsto Z_t(\omega)$ in a distribution sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics).
If you do this, the first derivative of $t \mapsto Z_t(\omega)$ at $X(\omega)$ would be equal to the jump size, which is equal to $1$.